# Dataframe Rolling greater than 0 count

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to count the number of returns greater than 0 as per below, however it returns a constant of 5, I am not sure what is the error below and tried to search around without success, please advise me

```
df['Countifup'] = (df['SPXreturn'].gt(0)).rolling(window=5).count()

SPXreturn Countifup
-1            0
+1            1
-2            0
+2            2
+5            3
```

I tried this and it works

```
df['Countifup'] = (df['SPXreturn'].gt(0)).rolling(window=10).sum()
```

What I understand is that I wanted the count but I should use sum

Comment: Is this Pandas? If so, you should add the pandas tag.

Comment: Did you try to replace 5 in your code with another number? What happens then?

Comment: If I replace with 10, it will constantly shows 10

Comment: @Jerrick Please, add example input and expected output

Comment: sure let me add

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you assuming that `df['SPXreturn'].gt(0)` filters dataframe, but actually it returns boolean mask:

```
df['SPXreturn'].gt(0)
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2    False
# 3     True
# 4     True
# Name: SPXreturn, dtype: bool
```

Here is how i would approach this problem:

```
df['Countifup'] = df[df['SPXreturn'].gt(0)].rolling(5).count()
df['Countifup'] = (df['Countifup'].fillna(0)
                                  .astype(int))
df
#    SPXreturn  Countifup
# 0         -1        0
# 1          1        1
# 2         -2        0
# 3          2        2
# 4          5        3
```